# Spark Streaming Kafka to ES

Tags: apache-spark, elasticsearch, spark-structured-streaming

I have a spark streaming job, which will read from kafka and write into elastic via Http request.

I want to validate each request from Kafka and change the payload as per business need and write into Elastic Search.

I have used ES Http Request to push the data into Elastic Search. Can some guide me how to write the data into ES via a data frame?

Code Snippet:

```
val dfInput = spark
  .readStream
  .format("kafka")
  .option("kafka.bootstrap.servers", "localhost:9092")
  .option("subscribe", "test")
  .option("startingOffsets", "latest")
  .option("group.id", sourceTopicGroupId)
  .option("failOnDataLoss", "false")
  .option("maxOffsetsPerTrigger", maxOffsetsPerTrigger)
  .load()

import spark.implicits._

val resultDf = dfInput
  .withColumn("value", $"value".cast("string"))
  .select("value")

resultDf.writeStream.foreach(new ForeachWriter[Row] {
  override def open(partitionId: Long, version: Long): Boolean = true

  override def process(value: Row): Unit = {
    processEventsData(value.get(0).asInstanceOf[String], deviceIndex, msgIndex, retryOnConflict,auth,refreshInterval,deviceUrl,messageUrl,spark)
  }

  override def close(errorOrNull: Throwable): Unit = {
  }
}).trigger(Trigger.ProcessingTime(triggerPeriod)).start().awaitTermination() //"1 second"
}
```

This way we are not able to achieve performance.

Is there any approach?

- Spark Version 2.3.2
- Kafka Partitions 20
- ES version 7.7.0

Comment: provide more details, what is the spark version being used ? And kafka partitions etc ?

Comment: Spark Version - 2.3.2, Kafka Partitions - 20, ES version - 7.7.0

Comment: any reason not to use Kafka connect?

Comment: I want to insert nested JSON into the Elasticseatrch via Spark Dataframe

Answer (score 0):

you can use `elasticsearch-spark-20_2.11` , it is very simple, fro more information [es-hadoop](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/hadoop/current/index.html)

```
EsSpark.saveJsonToEs(rdd, index, conf)
```